# compare Two variables of enum in java

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum Direction {
  UP,
  RIGHT,
  DOWN,
  LEFT,
}
```

i have two enum variables (a and b), in one case i have to check, if `b` is the next of `a`
for example
if `a=UP` and `b=RIGHT`.
and also if `a=left` and `b=UP`.
mabe something like this:

```
if(Direction.valueOf(a+1)==Direction.valueOf(b))
```

but when `a=LEFT` it would be out of bounds like an array right ?

Comment: yes, you'd need to manually wrap around

Comment: honestly I would not bother `valueOf()`. Just check their `ordinal()` with `%`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
public enum Direction {
    UP,
    RIGHT,
    DOWN,
    LEFT;
    
    private static final Direction[] VALUES = values();
    
    public Direction next() {
        return VALUES[(ordinal() + 1) % VALUES.length];
    }
  }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Direction a = Direction.LEFT;
    Direction b = Direction.UP;
    System.out.println(a.next() == b);
}
```

output:

```
true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (b == Direction.values()[(a.ordinal() + 1) % Direction.values().length])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).